# Proving or Disproving the Existence of Cycles in the Union of Distinct Walks Between Two Vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working on a graph theory problem and I'm wondering about the following statement:

"Union of two distinct walks joining two vertices contains a cycle."

I'd like to understand whether this statement is true or false, and if possible, I'm looking for a formal proof or a counterexample to illustrate it.

Could someone help me with a rigorous explanation or provide an example to clarify this statement in the context of graph theory?

Thank you!

Edits: I have added to definitions used by professor-

A walk in graph $\ (G\ )$ is a sequence of vertices $\ (v_0, v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n\ ) $ such that $\ (v_i, v_{i+1}\ ) $is an edge.

A walk is called a closed walk if it starts and ends at the same vertex.
A closed walk is called a cycle if no vertex other than the first one appears more than once.

Comment: Well, if you don't already know the two definitions in play by heart, your first step should be to look up both definitions. (This would also be a good detail to include in the question, since the definitions of "walk" and "cycle" sometimes do vary between sources.)

Comment: In a graph with four vertices $1,2,3,4$, the walks $1 \to 2 \to 3 \to 2 \to 4$ and $1 \to 2 \to 4$ are distinct and both join $1$ to $4$, but their union does not contain a cycle. [This counterexample may become invalid under different definitions of "walk," "distinct walks," and "cycle."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call $(v_i)_{i=0,\dots, n}$ and $(w_i)_{i=0,\dots, m}$ our two finite, different walks.

If one of those walks contains a duplicated vertex, it contains a cycle, so this case is settled. We can then suppose each of the two walks contains no cycle.

Call $k$ the greatest integer such that $\forall i \le k, v_i = w_i$.
$k$ is well defined because $v_0$ = $w_0$ and the two walks are finite.
$k < n$ because otherwise the two walks would be equal.

Call $l$ the smallest integer $> k$ such that $\exists j, v_l = w_j$.
$l$ is well defined because $v_n = w_m$.

So $C = v_k, v_{k+1}, \dots, v_{l-1}, v_l = w_j, w_{j-1}, \dots, w_{k+1}, w_k = v_k$ is a closed walk.
It cannot be reduced to one vertex, because $l > k$.

$C$ cannot contain a duplicated vertex coming from the same walk, because of our assumption.
$C$ cannot contain a duplicated vertex coming from two different walks, because of $l$ definition.
So $C$ is a cycle.